# Street Smart for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, installation, add-in, streets

I installed Street Smart Plugin for ArcGIS Pro

[image]

I Also added the plugin:
[image]
But the app is still disabled:
[image]

How to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

The [Street Smart for ArcGIS Pro User Manual](https://docs.cyclomedia.com/StreetSmart/ArcGIS_Pro/Street_Smart_for_ArcGIS_Pro_User_Manual.pdf) devotes pages 3-8 to how it can be installed and how to troubleshoot that installation.

Consequently, it looks like you may have only performed a few steps from that process.  I have not installed it myself, but I recommend following each step in those pages, and taking note of where anything did not work as described.